# Do I need root to install xposed modules?

Tags: rooting, customization, xposed-framework

Is it necessary to root my phone to install any xposed module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Root is a requirement to install the **Xposed Framework**, any additional modules can be installed (may not explicitly state root requirement) but need the Xposed framework to function, so in short yes root is needed.

Comment: As the other answer states, root is a requirement only if you're using the framework installer.

Comment: @AndyYan Thanks for mentioning that important point which I had overlooked! (I was used to installing Xposed framework without zip, so completely forgot about this other method:)) But one question. I am not an expert when it comes working with recovery, but doesn't installing a custom recovery require root also?

Comment: The "conventional" way of installing a recovery usually requires an unlocked bootloader (no root required). Furthermore, for many recent devices, only after installing a custom recovery can you flash a SU package and therefore achieve root.

Comment: @Andy Thanks for putting this up, perhaps OP can accept, the second answer. I am not really used to flashing zips though but thanks for the information

Answer (score 3):

You don't need root to install xposed modules and you can avoid using root to install the framework if you have a working recovery that can install unsigned zip files.

Comment: I think a distinction should be made here. The Android doesn't have to be rooted to install a module, but a custom recovery still uses root access within its environment to install those modules. So root access is indeed needed, just not necessarily in Android OS though.